# What is the best way to indicate an element to a specific point on an image by a line with Html & CSS?

Tags: html, css

[Please see this image if you don't understand what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5onVM.jpg)

I want to create a line that indicates a specific point on an image to an element.I have to do this with HTML and CSS.

If you don't understand my description then you can see the attached image, I marked all the areas by red color those I want to.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of themes you can have a look and learn from them. From your image (a bit low-res) I guess it's a social network UI. So you can fully use HTML5+CSS3 to make your own responsive site.

[image: Screenshot here]

I cannot write code for you but they are fairly simple. So please have a look of [this template](https://theme.crumina.net/html-olympus/16-FavPagesFeed.html). It looks close enough to your image and presents lots of good ideas of how to implement similar styles on your own site.